# Loss added to custom layer in tensorflow 2 is cleared when compiling

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, dropout

I am trying to port the implementation of concrete dropout in keras in https://github.com/yaringal/ConcreteDropout/blob/master/concrete-dropout-keras.ipynb to tensorflow 2. This is mostly straightforward, as tf 2 has most of the keras API built into it. However, the custom losses are being cleared before fitting.

After the model is defined, and before compiling it, I can see that the losses for each concrete dropout layer have been added to the model losses by the line `self.layer.add_loss(regularizer)` run when the layers are built:

```
>>> print(model.losses)
[<tf.Tensor: id=64, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-8.4521576e-05>, <tf.Tensor: id=168, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.000650166>, <tf.Tensor: id=272, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.000650166>, <tf.Tensor: id=376, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.000650166>, <tf.Tensor: id=479, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.000650166>]
```

After the compilation, however, `model.losses` becomes an empty list, and the assertion `assert len(model.losses) == 5` fails. If I choose to ignore the assertion, the fact that the layer losses are being neglected shows up in the warning `WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['concrete_dropout/p_logit:0', 'concrete_dropout_1/p_logit:0', 'concrete_dropout_2/p_logit:0', 'concrete_dropout_3/p_logit:0', 'concrete_dropout_4/p_logit:0'] when minimizing the loss.` when training the model.

After digging into the compilation code in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L184 I believe the problematic lines are

```
    # Clear any `_eager_losses` that was added.
    self._clear_losses()
```

Why is this being done at model compilation? And how can I add a loss per layer in tensorflow 2, if this is not the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that custom loss is not dependent on the model's inputs, you should add it using a zero-argument callable like this:

```
self.layer.add_loss(lambda: regularizer)
```

Comment: This succeeded in stopping tf from clearing the losses. However, I get the same warning that the gradients do not depend on the `p_logit` variables, though `regularizer` does depend on `p_logit`.

Comment: @user121664 Try this please: put the call to `super` in `build` method just right before 
the line calling `add_loss`. If it did not work, try put it after `add_loss` (though, it should be before that).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. No change regardless of where I put that call. I also tried moving the `self.layer.build` call, but that one needs to be before using `self.layer.kernel`.

Comment: @user121664 I am out of ideas now (it's a bit difficult without running the code myself). But one thing which surprises me is that why the loss is added to the wrapped layer! Why isn't it added to the wrapper layer itself (because it's not just a wrapper; it has trainable weights)? Like: `self.add_loss(...)`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried changing that, and it also doesn't seem to have changed much.

Comment: @user121664 Ah, I see. Can you please share your code or a minimal example to reproduce this warning in TF2?

Comment: Sure thing. Here's the repo (not very clean, I apologize): https://github.com/deepskies/mluncertainties/tree/cd-tf2
The concrete dropout code is in `models/cd.py`. The warning happens when I run `python train_network.py --model-type cd`

Comment: @user121664 After more than 2 hours of playing with this, I can confirm that this issue is only in eager mode. If you disable the eager mode using `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` it would work without problems (even without the fix I mentioned in my answer). You might have a better chance of getting an answer by opening an issue on Github repo of TF (provide a minimal reproducible example. I just used the `models/cd.py` and added some code for creating the model using `make_model` function and generated some dummy data using numpy, and then called the `fit` method of the model).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will prepare a minimal example and post it there tomorrow.

Comment: I am accepting this answer since it did solve the problem of the loss being cleared. The problem of gradients not seeing the parameter was a little separate. More details about that on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38607

Comment: @user121664 All right! I am glad you could finally solve the problem. And thanks for sharing the solution to the gradient problem.